# What is the inverse operation of the logarithm and which operation is "below" the logarithm in the "operation tower" if there even is any?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

["Operation Tower"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFpbg.png)

This "operation tower" is useful for the $\log$ in particular, since the $\log$ "decreases the level" of every arithmetic operation inside it, if there is any below, e.g.

$\log(a * b) = \log(a) + \log(b)$
$\log(\frac{a}{b}) = \log(a) - \log(b)$

$\log(a^b) = b * \log(a)$
$\log(\sqrt[b]{a}) = \log(a^\frac{1}{b}) = \frac{1}{b} * \log{a} = \frac{\log(a)}{b}$

but you can't simplify $\log(a \pm b)$ since there is no operation below $+$ or $-$

> You can **subtract** by **adding** (and the other way around) -> $a + (-b) = a - b$

> You can **divide** by **multiplying** (and the other way around) -> $a * \frac{1}{b} = \frac{a}{b}$

> You can **take the n-th root** by **exponentiating** with $\frac{1}{n}$ (and the other way around) -> $a^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sqrt[n]{a}$

**But what about logarithms?** As you can see, all the operations are each other's inverse and in case of the root/exponentiate equation, the power has to be modified in order to change the operation, i.e. $n$ becomes $\frac{1}{n}$ and division is one below the root in my so-called **operation tower**. Does the $\log$ have a place in my tower? Is it possible to modify the power so that the operation becomes $\log_n(a)$? Can you modify the logarithm (base or argument) so that the operation becomes exponentiation (e.g. $\log_x(a) = a^b$ or $\log_x(a) = b^a$ or $\log_b(x) = a^b$ or $\log_b(x) = b^a$ where $x$ represents the modified number)?

**I personally think that it's impossible because that would mean that you can simplify $\log(\log(x))$ which is not possible as far as I know.** I'm asking because it's confusing me that pretty much every operation can be represented in terms of its inverse, except for the $\log$ and probably a few other operations but let's stick to the basic ones for now.

***Thank you in advance!***

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but $\exp$ is the inverse of $\log$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, sorry that it's so confusing but my question is if the log can be represented in terms of its inverse, i.e. exp. I don't think it's possible but I'm really interested why that is, since pretty much every other operation can be represented in terms of its inverse.

Comment: "Does the $\log$ have a place in my tower?" Presumably not, since it's a unary operation, whereas everything else in your tower is binary.

Comment: "[...] so that the operation becomes exponentiation [...]" Maybe Knuth's up-arrow notation might be what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you, but are you sure log is unary? Wikipedia says that it's not, since it requires 2 operands, a base and an argument.

Comment: @AndreasLenz thanks, I'll look into it, maybe it is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Spi3lot You got me there! :-) I'm still going to say it doesn't belong to your tower, even considered as a binary operation. Just as $a + a$ gives $a \times 2$, and $a \times a$ gives $a^2$, $\log_a a$ does not give $a + 2$.

Comment: @TheoBendit okay, that makes sense, thank you :-)